# Override .NET connection string resolution

Tags: .net, azure, configuration, configurationmanager, azure-webjobssdk

Is there a way to override resolution of values from `connectionStrings` or `appSettings` sections at run-time? Can't find any appropriate methods in [ConfigurationManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that.

The issue I've got is a Nuget package which relies on `ConfigurationManager` but my application has custom settings storage (I'm talking to you Azure WebJobs SDK where `INameResolver` doesn't work with `ServiceBusAccountAttribute`). So the solution (if any) needs to be Azure friendly.

Answer (score 1):

For bindings with Azure Functions / WebJobs, INameResolver is the way to do this. 
ServiceBus should be going through that. I filed https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1347 to track fixing this. Please follow that issue for updates.

Comment: Thank you! I believe they fixed that in one of the later 2.x or 3.x betas but I have to stick to the stable which is 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to override resolution of values from connectionStrings or appSettings sections at run-time?

If you'd like to override the existing settings that you set in `App.config` or `Web.config` at runtime, you can try to specify ***App settings*** with same key under **Application Strings** on Azure portal.

For detailed information about **Application settings**, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).

> **App settings**
>
> This section contains name/value pairs that you web app will load on start up.
>
> - For .NET apps, these settings are injected into your .NET configuration AppSettings at runtime, overriding existing settings.

Comment: I need to look into my custom storage first by the key.

Comment: [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/) can help us access configuration settings and it is Azure friendly. But it does not provide methods to update configuration settings.